# Ruby, Cucumber, & Capybara: selecting using regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara

I am trying to select an input node using Capybara:

```
When /^the shopper clicks the "(.+)" button$/ do |button|
    first(:css, text: /^#{button}/).click
end
```

The scenario that triggers the above step is:

```
And the shopper clicks the "PAY" button
```

The button in the view will always start with the text 'PAY' but it is followed by a space and then the total price of the products e.g. '`PAY $150`'

The dollar amount will change but the PAY part won't. If I try the above code I get the following error:

```
And the shopper clicks the "PAY" button                   # features/step_definitions/shared_steps.rb:33
      unexpected '$' after '' (Nokogiri::CSS::SyntaxError)
```

How can I properly grab the PAY button using Capybara and Regex?

Comment: What type of element is it actually? a `<button>` , `<input>` , `<a>`, other?

Comment: It’s an input element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is that you have specified a `css` selector type but not actually specified a CSS selector.  Since it's an `<input>` element you could do

```
find(:css, 'input', text: /^#{button}/).click
```

However, since it's an input being used as a button I'm assuming it's of type submit, reset, image, or button. This means you can use the :button selector type (rather than :css) to make your clearer as to what you're actually doing. When finding a button Capybaras default behavior is to match on substrings so you should just be able to do

```
click_button(button)
```

which is the same as either of

```
find(:button, button).click
find_button(button).click
```

If that doesn't work for you please add the relevant HTML to your question.

As an aside, you should stay away from `first` whenever possible - it has a number of downsides.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you! Silly mistake on my part :).